# How to retrieve and store JSESSIONID cookie?

Tags: vba, http, jsessionid

I'm writing a web parser, everything is going well except the JSESSIONid which I cannot retrieve correctly. When I make the request with Postman I obtain a JSESSIONid cookie which I can further force into my VBA code, but that's not what I want. I want to get that cookie directly from my code.

Basically this is the part of my code which causes problem:

```
WHTTP.Open "POST", mainUrl & RequestAuth, False
WHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
WHTTP.Send strAuthenticate
jsessionIDCookie = WHTTP.GetResponseHeader("Set-Cookie")
jsessionIDCookie = Split(jsessionIDCookie, ";")(0)
```

I just obtained a jsessionIDCookie from the code, but it doesn't help me at the auth:

```
WHTTP.Open "POST", mainUrl & RequestAuth, False
WHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
WHTTP.SetRequestHeader "Cookie", jsessionIDCookie
WHTTP.Send strAuthenticate
```

When I force the jsessionIDCookie (retrieved from Postman) like this:

```
jsessionIDCookie = "JSESSIONID=lg49wqrAhHAGy5PirUBfBXM6uChBa67cXopvbDdK.i3jbseotaaff2"
```

Into my code, and ignore the first part more above, the authorization works fine!

Comment: See [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=cookie+user%3A2165759+is%3Aanswer)   I note you have tried something similar. `it doesn't help me at the auth` What happened?

Comment: Presumably you have a time based cookie so can use the Postman working cookie to quality assure what you get back from VBA? VBA sometimes sucks when it comes to this sort of thing btw

Comment: @QHarr effectively I saw it and tried to apply to my case. When I authenticate with force JSESSIONID from postman my code goes to the end of the process. With the ID retrieve by this method, I don't go further the authenticate form

Comment: Does the JSESSIONID vary that is retrieved between methods?

Comment: Yes, it does .. !

Comment: When you do the POSTMAN request and monitor the web traffic e.g. dev tools/wireshark etc do you notice any key differences in the actual request sent versus your VBA? Does your authentication needs to be encoded for example rather than basic authentication?

Comment: Yes I think so. the "host" header when set to "<calculated when request is sent>" returns a result, but it doesn't reutn anything when it's not set